# Why does the backing store of an array bind to the smallest type?

Tags: c#

In C# it is legal to write

```
Animal[] a = new Giraffe[4]; //with obvious relationships
```

Because arrays are covariant.  However, this is a breaking relationship.  It's a runtime exception to then apply a different type of Animal to this array because the backing store is a `Giraffe`.

```
a[0] = new Cat(); //KABOOM
```

Why doesn't the language create a covariant backing store?  This doesn't appear to be a limitation of the language because I can create this type of data structure myself:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A[] a = new B[2];
        a[0] = new B();
        a[1] = new C();//runtime exception

        var containerLegal = new Container<B, A>();
        containerLegal.Add(new B());
        containerLegal.Add(new C());//works fine
    }
}

class A { }

class B : A { }

class C : A { }

class Container<T,S> where T: class, S
{
    S[] s = new S[4];
    int currentIndex = 0;

    public void Add(S t)
    {
        s[currentIndex] = t;
        currentIndex++;
    }
}
```

I'm cheating a little bit cause I'm not using `T` in `Container<>`...but I think its a fair relationship anyhow.

Comment: Arrays are covariant because C# started as a java imitation and java arrays are covariant because of a design mistake. Since generics were implemented later they do not suffer (as you pointed out) from that same design flaw.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't that you *couldn't* store a reference to a C in that array (though I'm pretty sure it's nontrivial to implement). The problem is, if you permit that, code like this (note that this can be spread out over several unrelated methods, due to arrays being reference types) becomes wrong:

```
B[] bs = new B[1];
A[] as = bs;
as[0] = new C();
B b = bs[0]; /* It's a C, but we use it as a B, and a C is not a B! */
```

How does it go wrong? Well, if it doesn't notice and assumes a wrong object layout, you get all kinds of fun usually reserved for C, C++, and `unsafe` code:

- Re-interpreting an int as a float (or a reference to `T` as a reference to `U`, for recursive instances of such fun).
- Accessing uninitialized memory (or another object's memory)
- Calling a method with the wrong type or number of arguments.
- Using padding bytes as if they has any meaning.
- Overwriting metadata the GC/memory management system needs to operate.

Alternatively, you could restore safety by making all code *reading from* arrays do run-time type checks (as opposed to doing that check when *writing to* the array, as it currently does) and throwing an exception when an item has an unexpected type. That's slow and you'd just get the same exception in a different place (when you access the reference vs. when you store it), so you didn't "fix" anything.
That's because you can't fix it, such code is inherently broken. Your `Container` would exhibit the same problem if it permitted getting references back from the `S[]` (e.g., an indexer) *unless* it always returns the most general type (an `S`, not a `T`; otherwise you run into the same problem).

Comment: Value types are not relevant here, because arrays of value types are not covariant.

Comment: @svick Okay, noted (though I still think it would make the implementation more complicated, by further diverting arrays-of-values from arrays-of-references).

Answer (score 2):

Because that's what you told it to do.  That is the equvalient of:

```
Girafe[] g = new Girafe[4];
Animal[] a = g;  // girafe array has been created by this time;
```

Your statement is clear about all types, if you let the left side determine the type of the right, you'd run into some problems.  Consider..

```
Girafe[] g = GetGArray():
Animal[] a = GetGArray();
```

Does a equal g? If it doesn't then a NEW backing store would have to be created, if it does, then the compiler would have to be determining what happens based upon whether it was a new or a function call.  But then there is inlining...

Simpiliest to just do exactly what the line says.

Comment: I don't see how inlining enters the picture (then again, I'm not yet sure what that entire paragraph says) -- it's an optimization, it's not supposed to alter program semantics in any way.

Comment: His expectation seems to be that when he asks for an array of girafe's and assigns it to a variable of type array of animals, he gets an array of animals.  For that to happen, an array of animals has to be created sometime.  It wouldn't be too difficult for the compiler to do so in his example, it would replace the 'new Girafe()' with 'new Animal()', but what about functions that return an array of Girafe? The only way to maintain the type then is to copy it to a new array.  The inlining is just another hypothetical in regards to making it work that way.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, arrays bind to whatever type is specified when they are created.  The fact that even mutable arrays may be passed covariantly is a consequence of a few things:

1. Arrays predate generics, and until covariant generics were added to .NET there was no immutable type which could behave covariantly, so the arrays (which were all mutable) were the only thing that could be covariant.
2. To efficiently sort an array, one must be able to read items out of the array and write them back to it.  If one has a reference of type `Animal[]`, even if it points to a `Cat[]`, one may without any possibility of run-time error read out any item of that array into a reference of type `Animal` and later store it back *to the array from which it came*.  The ability to read out items might not be totally necessary if `Array` contained some methods like `CopyItem` and `SwapItem`, but being able to read out an item and write it back after performing many other changes to an array is more efficient than would be having to decompose every sort into a sequence of swaps.  While one could design a covariant interface which would allow an array or other collection to be efficiently sorted without requiring the sorting code to directly write anything into the collection itself, it's much easier to simply allow array covariance.
3. An array knows the type of element it's supposed to contain.  This allows it to enforce type-safety at runtime.  Although the generic collections added in .NET 2.0 also know their element type, most generic collections in Java don't.  If one tried to pass an `ArrayList<Cat>` to code expecting an `ArrayList<Animal>`, and if the latter code tried to add a `Dog` to it, there would be no way the `ArrayList<Cat>` could know that it was created as an `ArrayList<Cat>` and should reject the request.

If one declared arrays using syntax like `Array<Dog> myDogs = new Array<Dog>(34);` rather than `Dog[] myDogs = new Dog[34];`, then it might be possible to have multiple kinds of array references, so that e.g. `Array<Animal> myDogs = new Array<Dog>(34);` wouldn't compile, but `SortableArray<Animal> myDogs = new Array<Dog>(34);` would.  Neither Java nor .NET supports multiple array types, however.